# Кнопка как картинка - как убрать белую рамку? С++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Во вложении скрин программы. + прикладываю код, написанный в Visual Studio. C++. через WinAPI.

Как убрать эту белую рамку вокруг кнопки, или же сделать ее цветом фона?
Кнопка создается автоматически через ресурсы путём переноса ее на главное окно программы.

```
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        // Фон
        HBRUSH      hBrush;
        HDC         hdc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        RECT        rc;

        COLORREF g_Green = RGB(0, 249, 249);
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(g_Green);    // COLORREF g_Green = RGB(0,255,0);
        FillRect(hdc, &rc, hBrush);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        DeleteObject(hBrush);

        // Кнопка
        HWND CMDListControl = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDOK);

        HBITMAP hBitmap;
        hBitmap = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
        
        SendMessage(CMDListControl, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
        break;
    }
```

[image: Программа]

Comment: Уберите WS_BORDER и другие подобные стили из стилей кнопки. (стили в файле ресурсов)

Comment: <code>IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 246, 153
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "ОК",IDOK,45,56,166,21,BS_BITMAP
END<code>
Вроде ничего такого нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно Вам поможет установка стиля для кнопки `BS_FLAT`:

```
SendMessage(CMDListControl, BM_SETSTYLE, BS_FLAT, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));
```

Comment: Стиль BS_FLAT можно так же добавить в ресурсах напрямую.

Comment: Пытался. Но в таком случае ещё рисуется дополнительная черная обводка(
какие ещё предположения есть?

Comment: может стоит попробовать сказать ей что её стиль это её стиль минус WS_BORDER как рекомендуют выше =)

Comment: SendMessage(CMDListControl, BM_SETSTYLE, -WS_BORDER, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));

Что-то типо такого? не работает(

Comment: Вы используете push-button, и похоже вам ничего из вышеперечисленого не поможет. Вам нужно делать [msdn OwnerDraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) раздел BS_OWNERDRAW

Comment: Как вариант, можно создать регион без бордура нужной формы и присвоить его кнопке, ф-ции CreateRectRgn и SetWindowRgn.

Comment: По поводу BS_OWNERDRAW - 
Если оставляю из SendMessage только установку битмапа, то вообще не показывается ничего. кнопки нет. просто пустая вырезка в окне. Может как-то иначе тут устанавливаются картинки тогда?

Насчет региона не пробывал. сейчас проверю!)

Comment: BS_OWNERDRAW сложен тем, что нужно писать собственный обработчик прорисовки, иначе результат такой как вы описали. Регион будет проще.

Comment: А не подскажете, как узнать координаты x1,y1,x2,y2 кнопки для данного региона?

Comment: Или 45,56,45+166,56+21 или 0,0,166,21 за минусом ширины границы.

Comment: я имел ввиду примерно следующее:: SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) | ~ WS_BORDER);